# How to get multiple Word File uploads from user in Python and combine into one Word File?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to get multiple file inputs from a user (similar to the way that Excel VBA macros will let the user browse and select files).

I then want to combine them into one single file so that I can do some processing on the file.

Initially, I thought to make a loop and get file paths from the user? Is this the right way of thinking or is it possible to make something that looks more like a form where the user can simply browse and select files?

Comment: One idea if you want a GUI approach : You can use **filedialog** from the **tkinter** library to create windows-like file selection; you can then browse for files and select as required. There are plenty of references showing how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a loop to get file paths from the user.

```
def get_file_paths():
  file_paths = []
  for i in range(3):
    file_path = input("Enter the path to file {}: ".format(i + 1))
    file_paths.append(file_path)
  return file_paths

def combine_files(file_paths):
  with open("combined_file.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for file_path in file_paths:
      with open(file_path, "r") as infile:
        for line in infile:
          outfile.write(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  file_paths = get_file_paths()
  combine_files(file_paths)
```

This code will ask the user to enter the path to three files. The file paths will then be stored in a list. The combine_files() function will open the three files and combine their contents into a new file called combined_file.txt